# How to fix Dirty Electricity on an Inverter

Tags: inverter, emc, emi-filtering

I have been testing my inverter (Victron pure sine wave) as well as a few others with my Trifield EM100 meter. Most that I have tested show extremely high measurements from over 1,000mVp-p to well over 2,000mVp-p. Mine maxes out the meter at 2,000mVp-p.

When my iMac is connected to the inverter the external microphone gets a buzz. When on utility power there is no buzz. I am thinking that this is from the dirty electricity (or EMI) from the inverter.

Does anyone know how I can filter this out, or at least reduce it substantially.

Comment: You should use a high quality, known brand inverter for such applications. Filtering is possible, but complex and time consuming.

Comment: 2 Vpk-pk ripple isn't that much if we are talking about 120 or 230 V AC. Besides the audible noise, are you experiencing any electrical problems?

Comment: The whole ‘pure sine wave’ thing is a lie. Even the mains is far from ‘pure’.  The inverter performance will vary with load.  If the load is only the imac, that might explain the buzz. Earthing might also be an issue.

Comment: @Kartman, a myth, not a lie (which would be a deliberate intention to deceive for gain). Rest of it's right, though.

Comment: @winny Its 2mvp-p of high frequency noise, not just ripple. This noise radiates off all cables connected in the house. I have measured this with the TM100 meter. You can easily see it with an AM radio as well which picks up this noise. You can follow the radio all along the cabling in the house & hear this interference. Kill the mains circuit breaker & it disappears.

Comment: I see. What frequency range are we talking about?